# How to fix Lighthouse page speed FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST error?

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse

I'm trying to improve my websites page speed, Often when I'm using Chrome Lighthouse Audits i got this error:

```
Lighthouse: FAILED_DOCUMENT_REQUEST. Lighthouse was unable to reliably load the
page you requested. Make sure you are testing the correct URL and that the
server is properly responding to all requests. net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED.
```

IMG URL-> https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOXFW.png

I tried to figure what is the problem but i didn't find answer.
My websites hosted on AWS, including valid SSL and the page speed is standing between 85-95.

Any ideas?

I tried to find some good answers in Stackoverflow, Incognito mode, Audits Chrome, Chrome Extention.. Still getting this error..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and tried 1 day to fix it.
Apparently, the issue was with my MX domain records.

If you encounter this problem and land here looking for a result, do a DNS check for your domain before looking for blocked IPs from your servers and others.